# issues when classifying enterotypes on http://enterotypes.org/

Tags: classification, taxonomy

I would like to assign enterotypes for my metagenomic data by using the classifier on http://enterotypes.org/
I used the same format required on the website, but this submission still got an errors.

I am going to contact to author but I could not find any email on this site.

Anyone could help me? Thank you so much for your help.
sincerely yours,

Input format.

[image: Input format]

The error.

[image: The error]

Answer (score 0):

I also had some troubles uploading tables, try adding an empty "tab" in the 1st row (header) so that all columns align. I made some trials and it worked for me, but don't ask me why. I agree that some support in the website would be nicely appreciated.